# How to hide input text when not edit mode, then enable input text when click edit command button in lotus web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Basically I have a form. So I have a form where I display my document in web browser. There are some field with lotus notes field, and some field with html tag.

Right now, I have a command button to edit the form. Im using `@Command([EditDocument])` to edit. So when I click, it will triggered and make the form editable.

Not like usual lotus notes form for web form. I can enable edit and disable edit for lotus notes field in web, but not for the input tag.
I try to hide using JavaScript using onclick button but I'm using Lotus Notes button not html button.

HTML Input

```
<div class="form-group" id="date-container">
    <span class="group-read"><Computed Value></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control group-edit" id="P-AssignDate" name="PAssignDate" autocomplete="off" value="<Computed Value>">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-edit').click(function() {
        $('.group-edit').css('display','inline-block');
        $('.group-read').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Anyone know how to hide input button when the form not in edit mode, it just display the value, while when the form is in edit mode, unhide the input.

Comment: So what problem exactly you are facing? Like you are not able to trigger the javascript function through your button or the JS function in not hiding the field?

Comment: Because I am using Lotus Notes button in my form. I know how to trigger the button using normal HTML button but I don't know how to trigger the javascript using that Lotus Notes button.

Comment: I hope this will answer your question about using [JS with Loutus Notes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_USING_JAVASCRIPT_IN_THE_PROGRAMMER_S_PANE.html).

Comment: Okay will to to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can also check the url in the ready function. The url should change to ?editDocument once the document is in edit mode.

You can also create a computed field which evaluates to a value if the document is being edited and query this field during the ready function...

Comment: If using a hidden computed field, be sure to turn on the Generate HTML for All Fields property in order to make the value available to JavaScript code. (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_FORM_PROPERTIES_OVER.html)

Comment: Hi @umeli , I'm not understand on you second point. What you men by that?

Comment: You could add a hidden, computed for display field (for example with the name "editmode"). Or add the html attribute "hidden" to the field properties, And add a formula like @if(@isDocBeingedited;"1";"0"); then you could check if you are in editmode simply by doing something like if ($("editmode").val()==="1") { $(".edit-mode").show();}

Answer (score 0):

I would just swap the input field with a div (and vice versa when I want to go into edit mode again). 
Here is code for two buttons, one to make all input fields with the data-attribut dominofield into divs, and one to make those divs back into input fields:

```
// Bind function to Read Only button
$('#btnReadOnly').click( function() {
    // Get all input fields used for Domino
  var inputs = $('[data-dominofield]');
  // Process each field
  inputs.each( function() {
    // Build new DIV element
    var input = $(this);
    var div = '<div class="fieldReadOnly" ';
    div += 'data-dominofield="'+input.data('dominofield')+'" ';
    div += 'id="'+input.attr('id')+'">';
    div += input.val() + '</div>';
    // Insert ther new div element in front of input field
    input.before(div);
    // Remove input field
    input.remove();
  });
 });

 // Bind function to Edit button
$('#btnEdit').click( function() {
    // Get all input fields used for Domino
  var divs = $('[data-dominofield]');
  // Process each field
  divs.each( function() {
    // Build new INPUT element
    var div = $(this);
    var input = '<input type="text" class="form-control" ';
    input += 'data-dominofield="'+div.data('dominofield')+'" ';
    input += 'value="'+div.html()+'" ';
    input += 'id="'+div.attr('id')+'">';
    // Insert ther new input field in front of existing div
    div.before(input);
    // Remove div element
    div.remove();
  });
 });
```

I created a [fiddle to show this in action](https://jsfiddle.net/texasswede/8dv7fsx0/).